# Allowing only a range of inputs within an entry field in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to implement an entry box that accepts only a range of DoubleVar values. I have referenced this question that was asked [How to only allow certain parameters within an entry field on Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030454/how-to-only-allow-certain-parameters-within-an-entry-field-on-tkinter), but I want the user to be notified (using a change in font colour or anything) while they are entering the values. I've read the documentation but this is something that I haven't come across. 
I'm new to Tkinter, so please excuse me if this sounds very stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `KeyRelease` event of the `Entry` to a callback and check whether the input value is valid and within the required range, then update the foreground color of the `Entry` accordingly:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def check_value(entry, min_value, max_value):
    try:
        value = float(entry.get().strip())
        valid = min_value <= value <= max_value
    except ValueError:
        valid = False
    entry.config(fg='black' if valid else 'red')
    return valid  # in case you want the checking result somewhere else

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: check_value(e.widget, 10, 20))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `validatecommand` option for the `Entry`.

Some code fragments to show how it works:

```
root = tk.Tk()

vcmd = root.register(is_number)

e = ttk.Entry(pressf, justify='right', validate='key', validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'))

def is_number(data):
    """Validate the contents of an entry widget as a float."""
    if data == '':
        return True
    try:
        rv = float(data)
        if rv < 0:
            return False
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

This basically calls the validation function on every keypress. Only if the validation succeeds is the character added to the entry.

You can find a complete working example [here](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/resin-calculator/blob/master/resin-calculator.py).

**Edit**

Above is the "canonical" example of a validator. It allows or disallows characters into the `Entry`.

But you can also use it in other ways.
For example, you can always return `True`, but e.g. change the text color of the `Entry` to red if the value is not within the limits you want.

Comment: This can't work when trying to validate within a range, which is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @BryanOakley Validating if a number is within a range is basically just another step after checking that it is a `float`. I don't see why one couldn't do that.

Comment: Ok, what if the range is between 10 and 20? You can't type `1` because it's not in the range, so you can't type `10` either. If it was prepopulated with 10 and you want to change it to 11, it won't let you backspace over the zero in order to change it to a one. It's a major usability problem to disallow characters in this scenario.